# Link Error with application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have this link error in after the building, but no idea to the provenience. I checked all the external dependencies in the properties of the linker, but nothing. For you the body of the headers and cpp:

file mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <activemq/library/ActiveMQCPP.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Thread.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Runnable.h>
#include <decaf/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Integer.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Long.h>
#include <decaf/lang/System.h>
#include <activemq/core/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.h>
#include <activemq/util/Config.h>
#include <cms/Connection.h>
#include <cms/Session.h>
#include <cms/TextMessage.h>
#include <cms/BytesMessage.h>
#include <cms/MapMessage.h>
#include <cms/ExceptionListener.h>
#include <cms/MessageListener.h>
#include <include/IfacomAmqSender.h>
#include <include/IfacomAmqReceiver.h>

using namespace activemq::core;
using namespace decaf::util::concurrent;
using namespace decaf::util;
using namespace decaf::lang;
using namespace cms;

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void onMessage(const Message*);
    void connectionSender();


private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();



private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

file mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "include/IfacomAmqSender.h"
#include "include/IfacomAmqReceiver.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <activemq/library/ActiveMQCPP.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Thread.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Runnable.h>
#include <decaf/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Integer.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Long.h>
#include <decaf/lang/System.h>
#include <activemq/core/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.h>
#include <activemq/util/Config.h>
#include <cms/Connection.h>
#include <cms/Session.h>
#include <cms/TextMessage.h>
#include <cms/BytesMessage.h>
#include <cms/MapMessage.h>
#include <cms/ExceptionListener.h>
#include <cms/MessageListener.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

/*********** Definition  m_IfacomMessageBroker ******************/
    std::string brokerURI  = "failover://(tcp://localhost:61613?wireFormat=stomp)";     // localhost;

    // brokerURI = "failover://(tcp://localhost:61616)";        // localhost

    // Queue name
    std::string destName = "IFACOM-CMS";

    // Queue or Topic
    bool useTopics = false;         // true=Topic, false=Queue

    // SESSION_TRANSACTED or AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE
    bool sessionTransacted = false; // if true, commit all messages

    // Message parametres
    int numMess=1; int waitMillis=1000;

    // Definition of object m_IfacomMessageBroker
    //IfacomAmqSender m_IfacomMessageBroker(brokerURI,numMess, useTopics, sessionTransacted, destName,waitMillis);
    IfacomAmqSender* m_IfacomMessageBroker = new IfacomAmqSender(brokerURI,numMess, useTopics, sessionTransacted, destName,waitMillis);
    void MainWindow::connectionSender()
    {
        activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::initializeLibrary();
        // ***** Initialisation  **************************************************************
        //m_IfacomMessageBroker.initConnection();
        m_IfacomMessageBroker->initConnection();
        m_IfacomMessageBroker->getSession()->createTextMessage();

        //IfacomAmqReceiver IfacomAmqReceiverBroker(brokerURI,10, useTopics, sessionTransacted, destName,2000);
        //IfacomAmqReceiverBroker.initConnection();
        //IfacomAmqReceiverBroker.getConsumer()->setMessageListener(this);

     }

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    connectionSender();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

}
```

file main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <include\IfacomAmqSender.h>
#include <include\IfacomAmqReceiver.h>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication prog(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return prog.exec();
}
```

and the file IfacomAmqSender.h that is recall in the linkError:

```
#ifndef _IfacomAmqSender_h
#define _IfacomAmqSender_h
#include <activemq/library/ActiveMQCPP.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Thread.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Runnable.h>
#include <decaf/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Integer.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Long.h>
#include <decaf/lang/System.h>
#include <activemq/core/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.h>
#include <activemq/util/Config.h>
#include <cms/Connection.h>
#include <cms/Session.h>
#include <cms/TextMessage.h>
#include <cms/BytesMessage.h>
#include <cms/MapMessage.h>
#include <cms/ExceptionListener.h>
#include <cms/MessageListener.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace activemq::core;
using namespace decaf::util::concurrent;
using namespace decaf::util;
using namespace decaf::lang;
using namespace cms;


 class IfacomAmqSender : public ExceptionListener{

private:

    CountDownLatch m_latch;
    CountDownLatch m_doneLatch;
    Connection* m_connection;
    Session* m_session;
    Destination* m_destination;
    MessageConsumer* m_consumer;
    MessageProducer* m_producer;
    std::auto_ptr<TextMessage> m_message;
    long m_waitMillis;
    bool m_useTopic;
    bool m_sessionTransacted;
    std::string m_brokerURI;
    std::string m_destName;
    DeliveryMode m_message_delivery_mode;
    int m_message_priority;

    IfacomAmqSender(const IfacomAmqSender&);
    IfacomAmqSender& operator=(const IfacomAmqSender&);

public:


    IfacomAmqSender (const std::string&, int, bool,bool,const std::string&,int);
    //explicit IfacomAmqSender(const std::string&, int, bool, bool, const std::string&, int);
    //IfacomAmqSender(const std::string&, bool, bool, const std::string&);

    ~IfacomAmqSender();
    void close();
    void waitUntilReady();
    void cleanup();

    // KH
    void createConnection();
    void createSession();
    void createDestination();
    void createProducer();
    void initConnection();

    virtual void sendMessage(std::string);

    // Send a ActiveMQ Message
    virtual void sendMessage(std::auto_ptr<TextMessage>);


//--------------------------------------------------

    // If something bad happens you see it here as this class is also been
    // registered as an ExceptionListener with the connection.
    virtual void onException(const CMSException&) ;

    // Message Priority (0:Lowest - 9:Highest)
    void setPriority(int);
    int getPriority();

    // Message Delivery Mode
    void setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode);
    DeliveryMode getDeliveryMode();

    Session* getSession();

};
#endif
```

file IfacomAmqSender.cpp:

```
#include <activemq/library/ActiveMQCPP.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Thread.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Runnable.h>
#include <decaf/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Integer.h>
#include <decaf/lang/Long.h>
#include <decaf/lang/System.h>
#include <activemq/core/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.h>
#include <activemq/util/Config.h>
#include <cms/Connection.h>
#include <cms/Session.h>
#include <cms/TextMessage.h>
#include <cms/BytesMessage.h>
#include <cms/MapMessage.h>
#include <cms/ExceptionListener.h>
#include <cms/MessageListener.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "IfacomAmqSender.h"

using namespace activemq::core;
using namespace decaf::util::concurrent;
using namespace decaf::util;
using namespace decaf::lang;
using namespace cms;
using namespace std;






   IfacomAmqSender::IfacomAmqSender(const std::string& brokerURI, int numMessages, bool useTopic = false, bool sessionTransacted = false, const std::string& destName = "IFACOM-CMS", int waitMillis = 1000) :
        m_latch(1),
        m_doneLatch(numMessages),
        m_connection(NULL),
        m_session(NULL),
        m_destination(NULL),
        m_consumer(NULL),
        m_waitMillis(waitMillis),
        m_useTopic(useTopic),
        m_sessionTransacted(sessionTransacted),
        m_destName(destName),
        m_brokerURI(brokerURI) {
    }

    /*IfacomAmqSender::IfacomAmqSender(const std::string& brokerURI, bool useTopic = false, bool sessionTransacted = false, const std::string& destName = "IFACOM-CMS") :
        m_latch(1),
        m_doneLatch(1),
        m_connection(NULL),
        m_session(NULL),
        m_destination(NULL),
        m_consumer(NULL),
        m_waitMillis(1000),
        m_useTopic(useTopic),
        m_sessionTransacted(sessionTransacted),
        m_destName(destName),
        m_brokerURI(brokerURI) {
    }*/


     IfacomAmqSender::~IfacomAmqSender() {
        cleanup();
    }

    void IfacomAmqSender::close() {
        this->cleanup();
    }

    void IfacomAmqSender::waitUntilReady() {
        m_latch.await();
    }

//------ Init connexion ---------------

    void IfacomAmqSender::createConnection()
    {
        // Create a ConnectionFactory
        auto_ptr<ConnectionFactory> connectionFactory(ConnectionFactory::createCMSConnectionFactory(m_brokerURI));

        // Create a Connection
        m_connection = connectionFactory->createConnection();
        m_connection->start();
        m_connection->setExceptionListener(this);
    }

    void IfacomAmqSender::createSession()
    {
        // Create a Session
        if (this->m_sessionTransacted == true) {
            m_session = m_connection->createSession(Session::SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        } else {
            m_session = m_connection->createSession(Session::AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        }
    }

    void IfacomAmqSender::createDestination()
    {
        // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
        if (m_useTopic) {
            m_destination = m_session->createTopic(m_destName);
        } else {
            m_destination = m_session->createQueue(m_destName);
        }
    }

    void IfacomAmqSender::createProducer()
    {
        m_producer = m_session->createProducer(m_destination);
        m_producer->setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode::NON_PERSISTENT);
    }

    void IfacomAmqSender::initConnection() {

        try {

            createConnection();

            // Create the session
            createSession();

            // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
            createDestination();

            // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
            createProducer();
            m_producer->setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode::NON_PERSISTENT);

            // Indicate we are ready for messages.
            m_latch.countDown();

            // Wait while asynchronous messages come in.
            m_doneLatch.await(m_waitMillis);

        } catch (CMSException& e) {
            // Indicate we are ready for messages.
            //latch.countDown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    void IfacomAmqSender::sendMessage(string text) {
            try {

        std::auto_ptr<TextMessage> message(m_session->createTextMessage(text));
            // to set a property
            ////message->setIntProperty("Integer", ix);
        m_producer->send(message.get());
        message->setCMSTimestamp(System::currentTimeMillis());

        } catch (CMSException& e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    // Send a ActiveMQ Message
    void IfacomAmqSender::sendMessage(std::auto_ptr<TextMessage> amq_message) {
        try {

            amq_message->setCMSTimestamp(System::currentTimeMillis());
            m_producer->send(amq_message.get());

        } catch (CMSException& e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//--------------------------------------------------

    // If something bad happens you see it here as this class is also been
    // registered as an ExceptionListener with the connection.
    void IfacomAmqSender::onException(const CMSException& ex AMQCPP_UNUSED) {
        printf("CMS Exception occurred.  Shutting down client.\n");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        exit(1);
    }

    // Message Priority (0:Lowest - 9:Highest)
    void IfacomAmqSender::setPriority(int priority){m_message_priority = priority;}
    int IfacomAmqSender::getPriority(){return m_message_priority;}

    // Message Delivery Mode
    void IfacomAmqSender::setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode delivery_mode){m_message_delivery_mode = delivery_mode;}
    DeliveryMode IfacomAmqSender::getDeliveryMode(){return m_message_delivery_mode;}

    Session* IfacomAmqSender::getSession()
    {
        return m_session;
    }


    void IfacomAmqSender::cleanup() {
        if (m_connection != NULL) {
            try {
                m_connection->close();
            } catch (cms::CMSException& ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Destroy resources.
        try {
            delete m_destination;
            m_destination = NULL;
            delete m_consumer;
            m_consumer = NULL;
            delete m_session;
            m_session = NULL;
            delete m_connection;
            m_connection = NULL;
        } catch (CMSException& e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the errors are:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall IfacomAmqSender::IfacomAmqSender(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int,bool,bool,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (??0IfacomAmqSender@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H_N10H@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'm_IfacomMessageBroker''(void)" (??__Em_IfacomMessageBroker@@YAXXZ) C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\Activemq\ReleaseVersions\GUI-CMS-SENDER\mainwindow.obj   GUI-CMS-SENDER
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall IfacomAmqSender::initConnection(void)" (?initConnection@IfacomAmqSender@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall MainWindow::connectionSender(void)" (?connectionSender@MainWindow@@QAEXXZ)  C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\Activemq\ReleaseVersions\GUI-CMS-SENDER\mainwindow.obj   GUI-CMS-SENDER
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class cms::Session * __thiscall IfacomAmqSender::getSession(void)" (?getSession@IfacomAmqSender@@QAEPAVSession@cms@@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall MainWindow::connectionSender(void)" (?connectionSender@MainWindow@@QAEXXZ)   C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\Activemq\ReleaseVersions\GUI-CMS-SENDER\mainwindow.obj   GUI-CMS-SENDER
```

the command Line is:

```
/OUT:"debug\\GUI-CMS-SENDER.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"debug\GUI-CMS-SENDER.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "qtmaind.lib" "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012\\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib" "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012\\lib\Qt5Guid.lib" "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012\\lib\Qt5Cored.lib" "libEGLd.lib" "libGLESv2d.lib" "gdi32.lib" "user32.lib" "Qt5Cored.lib" "Qt5Guid.lib" "libapr-1.lib" "libactivemq-cppd.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH /PGD:"debug\GUI-CMS-SENDER.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Win32\Debug\GUI-CMS-SENDER.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012\\lib" /LIBPATH:"\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\Activemq\ReleaseVersions\GUI-CMS-SENDER\include" /TLBID:1
```

[image: This is the command line]

[image: Additional Dependencies]

[image: Input Linker properties]

[image: Here the project]

Comment: Have you defined these functions from `IfacomAmqSender.h` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I defined all the functions in the file IfacomAmqSender.cpp...you need the code of this file too?

Comment: yes, atleast show the function headers.

Comment: Ok...I added the .cpp file...

Comment: What's your linker command line?

Comment: Are you using `qmake` based build system? Please paste the linker command run, by using (n)make VERBOSE=1.

Comment: Side note: You have a crazy number of headers #included in each file. Pare them back to the minimum necessary for each file. If you did this while trying to figure out the linker problem, don't bother; headers rarely have any effect on linker behaviour.

Comment: Side note 2: Don't use `using namespace` declarations in header files. That pollutes every file that #includes the offending header.

Comment: You have a *lot* of code. Please provide a minimal test case, reproducing the issue. Refer to sscce.org.

Comment: I can't understand the request of @LaszloPapp....but MarceloCantos you ask me why I include all these headers, ok because I use it!! And for namespace I don't know how is the correlation with my link errors

Comment: @Laszlo  I post all the code that is necessary to understand....you know that if it would be possible...anyone post just the errors...

Comment: "#include <include/IfacomAmqSender.h>" -> why are you doing that as opposed to '#include "include/IfacomAmqSender.h"'? This is just a side note... you have an older installation system-wide? That could explain missing symbols as well.

Comment: But you are pasting a lot of irrelevant code which makes it harder to scroll through. Can you at least put all the code to pastebin because it is hard to scroll long SO embedded code.

Comment: @CecchinoSMI, as Marcelo said, post your linker command line. Will help.

Comment: @Laszlo Sorry but I don't know what I can exclude from the codes that I posted....

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: are you building everything into one executable, or you have a separate library for the "IfacomAmqSender" code, which you link againt the application?

Comment: @Laszlo IfacomAmqSender.h is a separate header file, that I recall as library..

Comment: Well, the mainwindow.h includes it as "...", the mainwindow.cpp includes it as <...>. That is inconsistent, too. Also, in your main.cpp, you are using *back* slash for the include rather than forward!

Comment: @Laszlo I change the include headers format as you said, using "filenam.h" in all my project, but the errors are not solved...

Comment: I add the Linker Command Line at the end of the post....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the recently added linker line, it seems that you are not linking against the library, actually. You would need to put this into your application's qmake project file:

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/your/library -lyourlibrary
```

If that does not work, please make sure you have a library version that you are trying to link against which contain the necessary symbols. I usually use "nm -a" o "objdump" on Linux, but there must be some equivalent version of those on Windows as well.

Edit: Since you seem to use Visual Studio as opposed to `qmake`, you need to ensure about two thing in your solution file:

1) The library built has the symbols. As for this, you need to have the symbols available, so make sure they are built into the library. You should have all the necessary files added to the project, but most importantly the source files (cpp).

2) You need to make sure when you build the application against the library that you have set up Visual Studio correctly in terms of library path and name. This setting can be done by the UI setting options.

Here are some screenshot for illustration:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes Laszlo...but I opened the project file in Visual Studio, i.e. I imported the .pro file with the add-in, so I think that is irrelevant if I include the libraries in the .pro file...

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: OK, you have not mentioned visual studio yet, but then you need to set up the library linkage in the Visual Studio project options as usual if you do not use the qmake project file, but the solution project, no?

Comment: yeah of course @Laszlo, I have the visual studio solution file, and I set all the libraries that I need in the linker options, if you want I can show you the libraries dependencies that I add...

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: please do so.

Comment: <lib;$(QTDIR)\lib;$(PLATFORM_SDK)\lib;$(CPPUNIT_DIST)\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)> these are the Addiotional Library Directories

Comment: <qtmaind.lib
$(QTDIR)\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib
$(QTDIR)\lib\Qt5Guid.lib
$(QTDIR)\lib\Qt5Cored.lib
libEGLd.lib
libGLESv2d.lib
gdi32.lib
user32.lib
Qt5Cored.lib
Qt5Guid.lib
libapr-1.lib
libactivemq-cppd.lib
ws2_32.lib>   and these are the Addtional Dependecies in Input

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: Why "%(AdditionalLibraryDir‌​ectories)" rather than "$(AdditionalLibraryDir‌​ectories)". You would need the dollar sign as opposed to the percentage. See the rest for consistency.

Comment: The "%(AdditionalLibraryDir‌​ectories)" is here for default, it is present in every project...

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought it is what you additionally specified. In that case, you have not specified your additional library, have you?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that all my libraries are specified in the additional dependencies, I have no dubt about the setting of the linker properties

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: please show the two screenshot of _yours_. Your linker command is missing the linkage, so I am afraid it is not set up properly, but it is better if you can prove me wrong. :-)

Comment: The screenshots are available....you note something wrong?

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: how is your library called that contain the IfacomAmqSender symbols?

Comment: @ Laszlo the IfacomAmqSender uses symbols contained in the libraries libapr-1.lib
libactivemq-cppd.lib

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: so you are not having a library separately for IfacomAmqSender, actually, as per your comment before? In that case, you do not need to care about it, but this is not what you said before. Are you just trying to put it together with the mainwindow and main file within the same executable?

Comment: I can't understand the first question....and for the second, yes why not....

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: in that case, please show a screenshot where we can see on the left which files you added to the project.

Comment: obviously the IfacomAmqSender.h is included in the folder External Dependencies

Comment: Show a screenshot. Also, why is it external, and not included in your solution and/or project?

Comment: @CecchinoSMI: it seems you did not add IfacomAmqSender.cpp to the Sources and IfacomAmqSender.h to the HEADERS. Click on the HEADERS/SOURCES on the left side with right click, and import them, and rebuild...

Comment: Ok @Laszlo I solved the problem in other way....I create i file .lib wich contains the IfacomAmqSender.cpp and I add this in external dependencies of linker in my IfacomAmqSender project solution

Answer (score 1):

Typically such problems arise when you forgot to include source files into your project.

If you are using qmake `.pro` project file, make sure you have included `IfacomAmqSender.cpp` into it (as pointed out @loentar):

```
SOURCES += (previous source files) \
           IfacomAmqSender.cpp
```

Or just add the `IfacomAmqSender.cpp` to Visual Studio project (Project — Add Existing Item... or right click in Solution Explorer — Add — Existing Item...) if you are not using qmake.

Everything should compile and link well then.

Comment: The error mentioned up, are showed in Visual Studio...so it is irrilevant if I add or not these file in the .pro file. I add the library directories in the linker properties....but the errors are not solved...

Comment: Also, that is not enough because you do need to set up the library path and library.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yes, you need to specify the library path and library for an external libraries (`.lib`). But the `IfacomAmqSender` is implemented in the `IfacomAmqSender.cpp` file, so no specific `.lib` library is needed.

Comment: The OP wished to have an external library. Please see the comment discussion. Hence, this is not a correct answer. I would delete it, but I will leave it with you.

Comment: Just scroll down `IfacomAmqSender.cpp`, this is the implementation file. If the OP wishes to have an external library, he'll need to compile it separately.

Comment: @DmitryMarkin: yes, he needs to compile separately, but in that case, your answer is incorrect since it is not enough what you wrote.