# Qt VS Add-In - link external libraries

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2012, linker, qt-creator

I want to include external libraries to my visual c++ Qt-add in project. Since my Qt project manager doesn't work I create a simple 'template' project with Qt-creator, and import the .pro file to Visual Studio via the add-in. I've added the commonly used libraries to the pro file in the creator, and with that I can build well, but in Visual Studio building gives me a linker error:

```
Error   2   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'OpenCL.lib'    D:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qtpnds\LINK
```

The full .pro file I tried to import:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-12-28T17:27:01
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = qtpnds
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindowpnd.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindowpnd.h

FORMS    += mainwindowpnd.ui

unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/lib/ -lOpenCL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include

unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/lib/ -lFreeImage

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include

unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/lib/ -lglew32

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include

unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/lib/ -lglut32

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include
```

In creator I can use the library, it works well.

### Using:

**Qt 5.2.0 MSVC 2012 /w OpenGL**.. OS: **Windows 7 Ultimate SP1, x64**.. Add-in version: **Qt-VS-Add-In 1.2.2**.. VS: **Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate**.

Is there any way to link libs in visual studio? `#pragma comments` and linking via project properties don't work, and I can't/don't know how to edit the .pro file in vs, without having to reimport it everytime I modify it.

I DID look for solutions, but I've only found posts about Qt-creator.
*For those who might say use Qt-creator instead of addons, I won't.*

**Edit**:

My opencl Lib is located in the `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/lib/` folder, and its name is `OpenCL.lib`. (`C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/lib/OpenCL.lib` is the full path). The same for the other libraries. The files and libraries work in Qt-creator!
The libraries added to the addittional dependencies too.

```
OpenCL.lib
FreeImage.lib
...
```

Without the Qt Add-in the files link well, but after transforming a project to Qt, they cannot be opened. I tried also creating a new .pro file with the add-in.

**Edit2:**

After removing the libs from the additional dependencies, I get unresolved externals for all OpenCL functions. Changing the pro file library paths to:

```
-L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib" -lOpenCL \
-L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib" -lFreeImage
```

does't work too.

Comment: Can you not set it like in the screenshots in here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20797690/2682142 Where is your opencl lib located, and how exactly is it called on your Windows?

Comment: it seems that your solution will work. I've set the additional lib directory to the default, and now get Qt library (Qt5Guid.lib
Qt5Widgetsd.lib) linker errors. I'm gonna find them too. +1 for the answer there

Comment: Make sure you do not mix release and debug builds, the paths are correct for them, and you have those libs supplied as well.

Comment: Finally works. I switched back to 32bit debugger, added the the qt library to additional dependencies, and linked the files. Now the pragma comments work too... How much I hate configure linker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add all the necessary Qt libraries along with their path explicitly if the conversion does not take care of that, which is the case, I am afraid. You will also need to add the opencl library along with its path.

Make sure you do not mix the debug and release builds becaues that can go haywire in the Microsoft environment.

Here you can see the two dialog where you can basically assign these additional dependencies and libraries to the default.

[image][image]